# How to automatically add and show all the product attributes when creating a new product

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm probably gonna be yelled at for this one. I have gone through some posts here, which seem to be the same issue (or almost on the same lines), But I didn't get anything out of them. Since, some are outdated, and some are answered very technically, which are above me...So, I'm gonna ahead and ask anyway. Hope, Someone would be able to guide me in the right direction.

Here it goes...

I'm working on a WooCommerce Site, and the client wants me to edit the "New product" page, in such a manner that all the attributes are pre-loaded with initial data, instead of the user clicking on them individually and adding each attribute one by one. They are fine with altering its values once all the other information has been filled up.

So, there is suppose to be some code or hook that needs to be added/edited in either functions.php or somewhere else. If someone can help me out what code and where to put it up, then that would be really great!

Thanks